# Mypy: annotating a variable with a class type

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I am having some trouble assigning the variables in a Python 3.6 class to a particular type--a Pathlib path. Following an example from [link](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html), I tried to create a `TypeVar`, but `mypy` is still throwing errors. I want to make sure that the class variables initialized in the `__init__.py` only receive a particular type at compile time. So this is just a check to make sure I don't inadvertently set a string or something else to these class variables.

Can anyone suggest the correct way to do this?

Here is some simple code.

```
import pathlib
from typing import Union, Dict, TypeVar, Type

Pathtype = TypeVar('Pathtype', bound=pathlib.Path)

class Request:

    def __init__(self, argsdict):

        self._dir_file1: Type[Pathtype] = argsdict['dir_file1']
        self._dir_file2: Type[Pathtype] = argsdict['dir_file2']
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Request.py:13: error: Invalid type "Request.Pathtype"
Request.py:14: error: Invalid type "Request.Pathtype"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither Type, TypeVar nor NewType are correct to use here. What you simply want to do is use `Path` itself:

```
from pathlib import Path

class Request:
    def __init__(self, argsdict):
        self._dir_file1: Path = argsdict['dir_file1']
        self._dir_file2: Path = argsdict['dir_file2']
```

If you annotate your `argsdict` as being of type `Dict[str, Path]`, you can skip having to annotate your fields entirely: mypy will infer the correct type:

```
from typing import Dict
from pathlib import Path

class Request:
    def __init__(self, argsdict: Dict[str, Path]):
        self._dir_file1 = argsdict['dir_file1']
        self._dir_file2 = argsdict['dir_file2']
```

---

Here's a brief explanation of what the various type constructs you were attempting to use/was suggested to you actually do:

1. `TypeVar` is used when you are trying to create a generic data structure or function. For example, take `List[int]`, which represents a list containing ints. `List[...]` is an example of a generic data structure: it can be *parameterized* by any arbitrary type.

   You use `TypeVar` as a way of adding "parameterizable holes" if you decide you want to create your own generic data structure.

   It's also possible to use `TypeVars` when writing generic functions. For example, suppose you want to declare that you have some function that can accept a value of any type -- but that function is *guaranteed* to return a value of the exact same type. You can express ideas like these using `TypeVars`.
2. The `Type[...]` annotation is used to indicate that some expression must be the type of a type. For example, to declare that some variable must hold an int, we would write `my_var: int = 4`. But what if we want to write something like `my_var = int`? What sort of type hint could we give that variable? In this case, we could do `my_var: Type[int] = int`.
3. `NewType` basically lets you "pretend" that you're taking some type and making a subclass of it -- but without requiring you to actually subclass anything at runtime. If you're careful, you can take advantage of this feature to help catch bugs where you mix different "kinds" of strings or ints or whatever -- e.g. passing in a string representing HTML into a function expecting a string representing SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the list of what the wrong attempts do, super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `TypeVar` with `NewType` and remove the `Type[]` modifier.

Comment: Say @Daniel thanks for the tip. This worked. I was just wondering if this is a new approach to assigning class types, or was I just misunderstanding the documentation? This definitely fixed the problem though :).

Comment: To be honest, never used TypeVar properly. What I understood was, if you do something like UserId = NewType('UserId', int), then "[...] UserId as a variant of int that is just an int at runtime." TypeVar I've only seen used to create container types, like some Stack[int]. Sources -> https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html and https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#defining-generic-classes

Although I do agree that mypy is still a bit confusing with docs! Hope it helps.